# Type 'Observable<SomeType>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<SomeType[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have interface:

```
export interface SomeType {
  value: string;
}
```

Method:

```
entities$(): Observable<Array<SomeType>> {
    let someType = <SomeType>{};
    someType.value = "value";
    return Observable.from(new Array(someType))
  }
```

And error:

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'. Type 'SomeType' is not assignable to type
>   'SomeType[]'.
>   Property 'includes' is missing in type 'SomeType'

I've tried different ways to create an array but none of them were working, so the question is what's the problem here?

Comment: use `Observable.of` instead of `Observable.from`

Comment: that's worked for me